# Incorrect TimeZone after Russia stop using Daylight Saving Time

Tags: .net, timezone

The problem appear in that the Framework 3.5 say that Russia supports DayLightSavings (return true), which not is the case today. Of course it then result in wrong offset back to asker of the method.

```
    var localTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
    bool useDaylightSavingTime = localTime.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now);
```

How do you pro's solve the timezone for Russia nowadays? They have no DST since 2012. This are applied and used til, primary, end of year 2019.

[Related link @ Connect]
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/686169/incorrent-utc-to-local-time-conversion-after-kb-2570791

[Related link WorldClock]
http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=166

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all seem to check out on my machine:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Russian Standard Time");
        var now = tz.IsDaylightSavingTime(new DateTime(2013, 10, 8));
        Console.WriteLine("Today: {0}", now);
        var prev = tz.IsDaylightSavingTime(new DateTime(2011, 10, 8));
        Console.WriteLine("Two years ago: {0}", prev);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

> Today: False
>   Two years ago: True

.NET retrieves the time zone rules from the registry.  Microsoft updates changes in local time zone rules periodically through Windows Update.  Be sure that your registry is up to date, it likely won't be if you haven't allowed Windows Update to deploy these updates.  You can see this by running Regedit.exe, navigate to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Russian Standard Time key.  The "Dynamic DST" subkey keeps the non-standard rules.  My machine has entries for 2010, 2011 and 2012.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I Will follow up on that, because my computer does not matter, the issue will affect win-servers where the packets are deployed. Also, because of this, it can be a non-question because development machines on this company is on Windows XP. Deployed servers on w2k3+

Comment: If they then refuse automatic updates on servers. Is this a recurring issue for such setup and where code use .net to achieve tz data? Because tz are changing..

Comment: Problems induced by people that make decisions like this should be handled by the people that make these decisions.  As long as they are unaware of the consequences of those decisions, they'll have no reason whatsoever to reconsider.  Of course there's nothing that we can do about it.

Comment: +1.  If you don't stay updated, there's no way the computer can know about things that have changed, such as this time zone change.  If automatic updates aren't allowed, you'll at least need to apply the latest time zone updates manually.  [Here is the most current update  from August 2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2863058), and [here is the TZ/DST support site](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/cp_dst) which you can watch for future updates.

Comment: Partyly. The .NET implementation does not have to be the one being used for tz. And yes, I think there are some stuff to do. If such decision is based on lack of knowledge, or was fitted in earlier requirement of the system; Communication and knowledge-transfer is a good try. I will investigate the reasons tomorrow. Interesting also to see if it's the Citrix own servers or the companys backend servers who are responding on TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.